# How to start the php-fpm server in docker?

Tags: php, docker

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        gcc \
        make \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN set -xe; \
    apt-get update -yqq && \
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
    apt-get install -yqq \
    apt-utils \
    libzip-dev zip unzip && \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    php -m | grep -q 'zip'

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get install -y nano
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cron
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN apt-get install -y procps
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libmagickwand-dev -y --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick-3.5.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN apt-get install -y ghostscript


COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
ENV COMPOSER_HOME /composer
ENV PATH $PATH:/composer/vendor/bin


WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get install -y git


COPY ./src /var/www
COPY  ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY  ./php/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/storage
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/bootstrap
```

I have docker file like this.

It can create the container but, there is no server in it.

in container, it accept only ip6

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I want to access fpm-cgi server by curl localhost 9000

Where should I set?

Comment: Why are you using `777` permissions? Where do you expose the service? Where do you create a user or are you intentionally running the process as `root` ? There is a lot missing here.

Comment: For no I want to test one container with out `nginx` my goal is entering container and make it work with `curl localhost 9000`

Comment: The `php:fpm` base image already comes with a `CMD` that launches the PHP-FPM server, but that speaks a FastCGI protocol and not plain HTTP.  If you want to use `curl` you either need to use a different PHP runner or put a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of it that can do the protocol translation.

Comment: AH,, I see, i understand, when using `docker composer` it works well. However now I want to use this in `aws` `ECS`. is it possible to use  FastCGI protocol to access between `nginx` and `php-fpm`

Comment: THankyou now I can summrize the problem. Let me start a new article and please close this.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, fix your permissions and do not expose services running as `root`.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN groupadd -g 101 nginx && \
    useradd -u 101 -ms /bin/bash -g nginx nginx

# ...

RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/storage
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/bootstrap
```

Next, you need to expose the service to the containers network, preferably as `nginx`.

```
USER nginx
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Answer (score -2):

try it in the docker container

```
service php7.4-fpm start
```

if it works, you can add it to Dockerfile as below

```
RUN service php7.4-fpm start
```

you can check stop,start,staus

```
service php7.4-fpm status|stop|start
```

Comment: There comes `php7.4-fpm: unrecognized service`

Comment: try it, apt-get install php-fpm on the terminal ...

Comment: `service` and similar commands broadly just don't work in Docker.  A Docker image doesn't persist running processes, so `RUN service ... start` (if it runs at all) won't have any effect.

Comment: `$php-fpm &` it works and server started, but `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` it shows only ipv6 `tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN`

Comment: and there is setting in www.conf `cat /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf | grep "listen ="` `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` so I guess ,,, somehow this `www.conf` is not loaded????